# self-adjoint operator and symmetric operator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, symmetric-matrices, self-adjoint-operators

we recently learned about self-adjoined operator with the formal definition $ ⟨Tv, w⟩ = ⟨v, Tw⟩$ for every $v, w$ in $V.$

In the other side we talked that self-adjoined can be represented as a symmetric operator (or matrix).

can you explain the geometric interoperation of a symmetric operator (matrix) and what does it mean?

also we learned that symmetric operator also always has real eigenvalues, I understood the part on the real eigenvalues, but why always exists such eigenvalues.

also can you help understand why for every two column in a Symmetric matrix are orthogonal (for every C1,C2 in A symmetric $<C1, C2> = 0.$), I understood the algebraic proof but I will be happy for some geometric intuition.

and finally what is the connection between the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A symmetric with the the linear operator that A represents? (we learned that somehow its related to the direction that the operator scale/ squeeze the plane).

thank you

Comment: Symmetric matrices will not have orthogonal columns necessarily, e.g. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. You might be thinking of orthogonal matrices, which satisfy $\langle Tv, w \rangle = \langle v, T^{-1}w\rangle$ for all $v, w$. Or, you might be thinking of the eigenspaces, which are orthogonal for self-adjoint (or, indeed, normal) operators.

Comment: @user793679, can you please expand on your orthogonal point when thinking of eigenspaces, I am not understanding it. Thanks

Comment: The eigenspaces of a self-adjoint operator are pairwise orthogonal. That is, if you take two eigenvectors $v_1, v_2$ with different eigenvalues, then $\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle = 0$ (see my edited answer below). This is different to having orthogonal columns.

Comment: @user793679, sorry for any inconvenience, I understood the proof, but can you give some intuition for why they are they orthogonal?

Comment: As in, geometric intuition? Not really. As my answer indicates, my geometric intuition uses the orthogonal eigenspaces and real eigenvalues as a starting point. To me, these conditions are the translation of self-adjointness into the language of geometry.

Comment: okey, I think I got the idea now

Comment: @user793679, basically the formal definition insures that we get real eigenvalues from the operator T, and thus there can't be any kind of rotation happening in any plane. All of the orthogonal spaces must stretch, shrink, and/or reflect ?              what I am not sure of that how to the formal definition insures that T has eigenvalues?

Comment: That's a good question. There's always at least some eigenvalues in every operator on finite-dimensional space, but the eigenspaces need not sum to the entire space in general. This is equivalent to being diagonalisable, and also turns out to be equivalent to $\operatorname{ker}(T - \lambda I)^2 = \operatorname{ker}(T - \lambda I)$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$. We can use this characterisation without much difficulty on $T$. As for proving this characterisation, I'm not sure how to do that off the top of my head.

Comment: @user793679, basically the formal definition insures that we get real eigenvalues from the operator T, and thus there can't be any kind of rotation happening in any plane. All of the orthogonal spaces must stretch, shrink, and/or reflect ? so that's true ?

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically, it's probably best to think about self-adjoint operators in terms of their eigenspaces. An operator on a finite-dimensional inner product space is self-adjoint if and only if its eigenvalues are real and its eigenspaces are orthogonal and sum (directly) to the whole space.

The real eigenvalues means, roughly, there can't be any kind of rotation happening in any plane. All of the orthogonal spaces must stretch, shrink, and/or reflect.

Here's some examples, and geometric reasoning to support why/why not they are self adjoint:

### Rotations in a plane

As stated before, there can't really be rotations while remaining self-adjoint, as these produce complex eigenvalues (of modulus $1$, in fact).

### Projections onto a line/plane/subspace by least distance

Yep! These are self-adjoint. In essence, we are decomposing the space into the space we are projecting onto (the range), and its orthogonal complement (the kernel). We are leaving the vectors in the range alone (i.e. multiplying them by $1$), and shrinking the vectors in kernel to nothing (i.e. multiplying them by $0$).

### Reflections, by least distance

Also self-adjoint. Rather than shrinking the complement to nothing, instead we are reflecting and multiplying the vectors by $-1$. This still makes them self-adjoint, but it will mean that the map is not positive-(semi)definite.

### Projections onto one subspace, along a complementary subspace

This is a more general type of projection, which won't generally be self-adjoint, as the complementary subspace need not be orthogonal to the original subspace.

Hope that helps!

---

EDIT: Regarding orthogonal eigenspaces, suppose that $T : V \to V$ is self-adjoint, and $v_1, v_2$ are eigenvalues for distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$. We simply need to show $\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle = 0$.

To prove this, consider
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle &= \langle \lambda_1 v_1, v_2 \rangle \\
&= \langle Tv_1, v_2 \rangle \\
&= \langle v_1, Tv_2 \rangle \\
&= \langle v_1, \lambda_2 v_2 \rangle \\
&= \overline{\lambda_2} \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle \\
&= \lambda_2 \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle,
\end{align*}
where the last line uses the fact that $\lambda_2$ is real. Thus, we have
$$(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle = 0 \implies \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle = 0$$
since $\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

On the real eigenvalues question

Let $(\lambda,v)$ be any pair eigenvalues and eignevectors of $A$. Since $A=A^T=A^\ast$,
$$\langle Av,Av\rangle=v^*A^*Av=v^\ast A^2v=v^*(A^2v)=\lambda^2||v||^2.$$

Therefore $\lambda^2=\frac{\langle Av,Av\rangle}{||v||^2}$ is a real nonnegative number. Hence $\lambda$ must be real.

Comment: This assumes $V = \Bbb{C}^n$ or $\Bbb{R}^n$.